# Ошибка в break не могу исправить

Tags: javascript, if, break

```
var guess = prompt("Угадайте букву или нажмите Отмена для выхода из игры.");

if (guess === null) { 
  break; // Пишет что тут ошибка!
} else if (guess.length !== 1) {
alert("Пожалуйста, введите только одну букву.");
} else { 
  // Обновляем состояние игры
}
```

Comment: что по меткам? или вы не определились между java и javascript?

Comment: @SKIP, `prompt`  нет в java